# How to re order content types in list using PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell, content-type, custom-list

In a Custom List there are more than 1 content types e.g. `"Content Type 1", "Content Type 2"` including OOB `Item`.

Using PowerShell how can they be reordered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

$url = "http://sharepoint/sites/site1"
$order = "Content Type 1", "Content Type 2", "Item"

$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.ListS["Your Custom List"]

if($list.ContentTypes[$order[0]] -ne $null)
{
    $currentListOrder = $list.RootFolder.ContentTypeOrder

    for($i = $currentListOrder.Count; $i -gt 0; $i--)
    {
        $lct = $currentListOrder[$i]
        $disableoutput = $currentListOrder.Remove($lct)
    }

    $currentListOrder.Add($list.ContentTypes[$order[0]])

    $disableoutput = $currentListOrder.Remove($currentListOrder[0])

    foreach($ctToAdd in $order | where { $_ -ne $order[0]})
    {
        $currentListOrder.Add($list.ContentTypes[$ctToAdd])
    }

    $list.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = $currentListOrder
    $list.RootFolder.Update()
}
```

This is tested and working fine. If you need any explanation of the script I am happy to add comments.

Comment: That is a great help and solves my problem!! Cheers. I have written a CSOM PowerShell function  as well and I have posted as an answer, if this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The PowerShell function using `Client Object Model`. We don't need to be on the SharePoint server to run the below function. Just need client components installed on our machine

Link to download [SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35585)

Below function can also referred on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/asadrefai/7a22c002959cf233f8e5) and [This Blog](https://sharepointstew.wordpress.com/2015/04/11/reorder-content-types-in-sharepoint-list-csom-powershell/)

```
#Load SharePoint client assemblies
#
Try{
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll'
}

catch {
    Throw "Unable to load SharePoint Client runtime"
}


function Reorder-ContentTypesInList()
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][System.Net.NetworkCredential]$credentials,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$listName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$ContentTypeNamesInOrder
    )

    begin{
        try
        {
            #get Client Object
            #
            $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($url)
            $context.Credentials = $credentials

            #Retrieve List
            #
            $list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listName)
            $context.Load($list)
            $context.ExecuteQuery()


            #Get Content Types from a list
            #
            $contentTypes = $list.ContentTypes
            $context.Load($contentTypes)
            $context.ExecuteQuery()
        }
        catch{
            Write-Host "Error while getting context. Error -->> "  + $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    process{
        try
        {

            #Making generic list of content type ids in passed order
            #
            $ctList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ContentTypeId]
            Foreach($ct in $ContentTypeNamesInOrder){
                $ctToInclude = $contentTypes | Where {$_.Name -eq $ct}
                $ctList.Add($ctToInclude.Id)
            }


            #Updating content type order
            #
            $list.RootFolder.UniqueContentTypeOrder = $ctList
            $list.Update()
            $context.Load($list)
            $context.ExecuteQuery()

            Write-Host "Content Types Reordered successfully" -ForegroundColor Green

        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host ("Error while reordering content types in a list. Error -->> " + $_.Exception.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
    end{
        $context.Dispose()
    }
}

$credentials = Get-Credential 
$ContentTypesInOrder = "Content Type 1", "Content Type 2", "Content Type 3"
Reorder-ContentTypesInList 'http://YourSite' $credentials 'Your List Name' $ContentTypesInOrder
```

Answer (score -1):

only by removing and re-adding...

had the same problem... googled whole 3 days for sorting content types... google page 20 told me, it's only possible by removing and re-adding!

Comment: And how do yo remove and add Content Types via PowerShell? This is what OP is asking. Please update your answer. Thank You