# Hide a content type via REST for Power Automate

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

Trying to hide content types in a SharePoint library using REST in Power Automate but it doesn't seem to be changing the value, however, I get no errors.

[image: ContentType]

I found this for the REST endpoint

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj246627(v=office.15)

For now, I'm hardcoding 1 of the content types deployed to the library, I can configure it all properly with variables later when I get the basics working to hide 1 content type from the library.

I know the library and content type are correct as when I navigate to the following URL in the browser it comes back with all the info on that content type for the library.

> `https://MYTENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/SITENAME/_api/web/lists('31df72f6-89d2-4286-b614-dce841d6bba1')/contenttypes('0x0101006EE69677D2A0AB42A78310A12E7F239D010100081AA30D723AD74492557A0200BE698C')`

Built a Power Automate, and set the body to

```
    {
  "__metadata": { "type": "SP.ContentType" },
  "Hidden": true
}
```

[image: Send HPPT request]

However, the output is always

```
{
  "d": {
    "Hidden": false
  }
}
```

[image: Result]

I've tried changing the body to

```
{
  "d": {
    "Hidden": true
  }
}
```

I've also tried PATCH instead of POST

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I played around with this a bit using CSOM and a console app. While it is possible to set the hidden property of a list content type, that's not the way to configure the New button order and visibility.

What you are trying to achieve is set via the UniqueContentTypeOrder property on the root folder of the list.

You can get the value using the REST endpoint

```
https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[sitename]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/rootfolder/uniquecontenttypeorder
```

However I wasn't able to set this via REST either. It may not be supported.

The good news though is that you can hack together the relevant CSOM xml request that you can use to simulate a CSOM call from within a flow. For example the following works for me.

[image]

The variable parts of the xml are highlighted below with green being the content type ids to include and the pink being the object path to the root folder of the list, where

1. Is a random guid
2. Is a special hard coded guid 740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7
3. Site Id
4. Web Id
5. Unique id of the list/library root folder (not the list id)

[image]

Here is a copy/paste version of the xml.

```
<Request AddExpandoFieldTypeSuffix="true" SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0" ApplicationName=".NET Library" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009">
<Actions>
    <SetProperty Id="2" ObjectPathId="1" Name="UniqueContentTypeOrder">
        <Parameter Type="Array">
            <Object TypeId="{da0f1e90-296f-480e-bc27-cefe51eff241}">
                <Property Name="StringValue" Type="String">0x010100C8574546B89B6E43861F617C2EEA2056</Property>
            </Object>
            <Object TypeId="{da0f1e90-296f-480e-bc27-cefe51eff241}">
                <Property Name="StringValue" Type="String">0x010100B5A6134050CE2646B54CC822F76F69CB00580084510CE58443999901EC89FD8B90</Property>
            </Object>
        </Parameter>
    </SetProperty>
    <Method Name="Update" Id="3" ObjectPathId="1"/>
</Actions>
<ObjectPaths>
    <Identity Id="1" Name="667eb9a0-7044-2000-4cca-091ace2a0007|740c6a0b-85e2-48a0-a494-e0f1759d4aa7:site:bc4693a3-620d-4b29-bc4a-38f877ecf5af:web:d9a7b9ac-d196-47c7-8bc6-70280e027475:folder:5fcc94ab-68a1-4426-823a-3bfa8958afa6"/>
</ObjectPaths>
```

**NOTE:** The api doesn't seem to like line breaks/formatting so be sure to remove them before putting into your flow activity.

Hope that helps!

For reference, here's a link to doing the same thing via PowerShell [How to re order content types in list using PowerShell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144423/how-to-re-order-content-types-in-list-using-powershell)